# Docker Tomcat response 404 after stop and start

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat, microservices

I've a simple WAR file in a Docker container.

I build it with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat

COPY /target/my.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

For build it use this command:

```
docker build -t tomcat-img .
```

At first deploy use this command:

```
docker run --name tmc -p 8088:8080 tomcat-img:latest
```

At this time all works very good (at page http://localhost:8088/my), but if i stop the container with "docker stop tmc" or use CTRL + C, and then docker start tmc this does not work anymore.

The main page at http://localhost:8088/ response properly TOMCAT, but in http://localhost:8088/my i receive 404.

thank you all

Comment: Did you check docker logs of tmc? Any useful message?

Comment: I resolve starting the container as root